# Validate the number of pixels of UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

In my APP, user is going to upload an UIImage. But I need to make sure the image is larger than 50*50 and smaller than 400*400 pixels. How could I do that?

I found out for a certain UIImage object, CIImage Property has .Height, .Width and .bitsPerPixel properties and I'm not sure whether these are relevant. I noticed that all these properties are relate to bitmap, but I have no experience of bitmap.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use RBResizeImage

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
CGImageRef cgimage = image.CGImage;

size_t pixelsWide  = CGImageGetWidth(cgimage);
size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(cgimage);
```

Swift:

```
var bitmapByteCount = 0
  var bitmapBytesPerRow = 0

  //Get image width, height in pixel
  let pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(inImage)
  let pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(inImage)
```

And do your validation like:

```
if (pixelsWide >=50 && pixelsWide <=400)
{
if (pixelsHigh >=50 && pixelsHigh <=400)
 {
   // Add your code here. 
 }
}
```

For getting more details:

Check the SO post:

[How to get Pixel data from UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/5215474)

Please put look on 
[**Getting the raw data**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262893/5215474)

Comment: Thanks for help. I just tested your answer with the other one, which using size property of an UIImage Instance. I used image.size.width * image.scale . And the result is exactly the same as you method. Just wondering are they basically the same thing? And can I say for sure the results are actual pixel instead of iOS points? Because I heard that number of pixel may equal 2* or 3* points.